# Android development with Samsung Galaxy S3

Tags: android, cordova, samsung-mobile-sdk

I am new to Android development, i need some start up advice, tools and resources to start.

I have Samsung Galaxy SIII **(GT-I9300)** mobile **(Andriod 4.3)** and Laptop with Windows 7 OS.

What is the first step, which software i need to download, SDK's, IDE's, tutorials, Framework like PhoneGap etc.

Answer (score 0):

you should start reading https://developer.android.com/training/index.html and downloading Android Studio

Answer (score 0):

You can use the playlist from slidenerd on youtube, it has everything you need to get started. 
https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLonJJ3BVjZW6hYgvtkaWvwAVvOFB7fkLa

Comment: Its look like a bible, thanks man i will follow this video tutorial. :)